# Java code snippet logic

Tags: java, logic

I cannot see what I am doing wrong here. Here is the code I am having trouble with :

```
String tempSummaryString = "SUMMARY:";
for(int z = 0; z<attributeList.size() ; z++)
{
    System.out.println(attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length()));
    if(attributeList.get(z).length() > tempSummaryString.length() && 
       attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length() == tempSummaryString)
    {
            event.setTitle(attributeList.get(z).substring(tempSummaryString.length(),attributeList.get(z).length()));
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that the program never goes into the if (does not execute the event.setTitle method). When I print the value of

```
attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length())
```

I get the following:

> SUMMARY:

So I am stumped about why it is not entering the if! I don't get it!

Hopefully someone can point out a stupid mistake I am making because I really dont know what else to do

Comment: What is the result of `attributeList.get(z)`? It might be an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've fallen for the old `==` vs `equals()` problem. You are using `==`, which unlike javascript, does an *identity* comparison (ie are these the *same* objects).

Try this:

```
attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length())
    .equals(tempSummaryString) // equals() not ==
```

Also, you should consider using the [foreach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) syntax for your loop:

```
for (String attribute : attributeList) {
    if (attribute.substring... // forget about attributeList.get(z) and even z
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare strings using the `==` operator (as in `attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length()) == tempSummaryString`), use the `String.Equals` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this: `attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length())== tempSummaryString`. You compare *references*, not *string contents*. Use `String.equals(otherString)` to that end.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the Strings with equals().

```
attributeList.get(z).substring(0,tempSummaryString.length()).equals(tempSummaryString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings with `==`, while you should use the String class' `.equals()` method.